# npm http-server path back

Tags: node.js, npm, path, httpserver

If I do `"start-example-html": "http-server -c-1 -o ./"` thats fine but if I do `"start-example-html": "http-server -c-1 -o ../"` the explorer retrieves the same path as `./`, so I cannot refer to the current's directory level up.
I tried `"start-example-html": "http-server -c-1 -o ../client/index.html"` what is I think would be the correct path but does not work because cannot go upwards as mentioned.

Preject path structure:

```
project
│   README.md
│   file001.txt    
│
└───api
│   │   package.json
│   │   ....
│   └───node_modules
│
└───client
    │   index.html
    │   ....
```

I could index.html around to a path I can reach, but is it not possible to choose any path of your choice with npm's http-server?

Comment: Why don't you just install `http-server` in your root directory? If you want to run the script in `api` you can use `--prefix`.

Comment: yea, moving the html file, or the installation path of the `http-server` are options I considered, however if you want to keep one package json and one node-modules folder locally and together would not be possible so I found surprising I could not set a path of my choice that is a level up (`../`) from the node modules current (`./`)

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but have you tried [`serve`](https://npmjs.com/package/serve) instead?

Comment: The repo im trying to run uses npm http server but I will check that out thanks